# How to properly take care of registering user's login/logout and not sending notifications to logout users?

Tags: push-notification

I have been struggling with following problem for quite some time, but I haven't found proper solution. The problem is, if we have application that has login/logout functionality and let's say that for some parts of the application, like news you do not need to be logged in, but for commenting you need have an account. I am using Firebase for notifications.

So in this scenario, I want to send notification when new post is posted on the platform. For that I use topics. I also wont to notify user when someone replies to their comment. For this I send notification to device token, targeting devices where user is logged in. It is easy to have mechanism to register new device token into my database. When user logs in, mobile developer needs to implement functionality to read and send me new device token, so I can save it in database.

However the problem raises when user logs out from application, I need mobile developer to notify me on specific endpoint on back-end so I can delete device from database (e.g. /auth/logout). But the main problem here is that we rely on the internet, but there are so many reasons why internet connection can fail prior to notifying to delete device from database. In that case device token will not be deleted from database and when someone replies to user's comment, I will send notification to the device and user will receive notification even if they are logged out.

So I am asking what is the proper way to handle this situation? How to prevent sending notification when user is logged out?

Answer (score 0):

One way is prevent logout until request is not through, but probably it is not a nice user experience.

Other is to try to remove registration token, so it Firebase could not propagate it to the device.
From documentation, I believe that you are looking for `FirebaseMessaging.deleteToken()` [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#deleteToken())

Also, on next startup of application, new token will be created, which can be turned off and then delayed until login.